# Nullable annotation for local usage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have code with class method, lets say:

```
+ (NSString*) build:(NSString*) id domain:(NSString*) domain {
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@/%@", domain, id];
}
```

I want to add to it `nullable` annotation as:

```
+ (NSString*) build:(nonnull NSString*) id domain:(nonnull NSString*) domain {
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@/%@", domain, id];
}
```

I know annotations we use for Swift API to convert staff to Optional but I found that for private use its really helpful.

for example if I'll call this method with `nil` like:

```
[Helper build:id  domain:nil ]
```

It will throw warning

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-nill ...

So every developer knows that this method receives non-nullable values

- Is there any restrictions?
- And why I didn't find open source code that widely use these annotations inside the code?

My application should run on iOS 7+

Answer (score 0):

You bring up a good point. I also have not really seen a lot of `Obj-C` code that uses annotations. But I find is extremely helpful especially when working on a project that contains both `Swift` and `Obj-C`. I found this **really** helpful [link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) that you should checkout! It is on the official `Swift` blog. One thing that I do see about your restriction question is:

> This feature was first released in Xcode 6.3 with the keywords __nullable and __nonnull. Due to potential conflicts with third-party libraries, we’ve changed them in Xcode 7 to the _Nullable and _Nonnull you see here. However, for compatibility with Xcode 6.3 we’ve predefined macros __nullable and __nonnull to expand to the new names.

Hope this helps, and I'll be looking for more inputs on this as well!